# How NOT to save scroll position of a DialogFragment when it's dismissed?

Tags: android

I have a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` which shows a list of items. If I open it and scroll to say item 20 then close it and open it again the `RecyclerView` inside the bottom sheet is still scrolled to item 20 and the bottom sheet itself is in collapsed state.

I want the dialog to reset its scroll position on dismiss but keep it on configuration change (for example I don't want to lose scroll position after rotation when the dialog is open). I tried calling `recyclerView.scrollTo(0, 0)` in `onDismiss` but it didn't work.

[image]  [image]